# about angular provider's component event transfer without service

Tags: angular, typescript

I create 4 test component now, there are:

1. main-component
2. page-A-component
3. page-B-component
4. action-component

**action-component.html** only has one button elm, he got one click event, like this:

```
<button (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
```

**action-component.ts** has addEvent、onSubmit method and eventList array, like this:

```
eventList = [];

addEvent(event) {
    this.eventList = [...this.eventList, event];
}

onSubmit() {
    this.eventList[0].handle();
}
```

and **page-A-component.html**、**page-B-component.html** is here:

```
<p>Page A</p>
<action></action>
```

.

```
<p>Page B</p>
<action></action>
```

**page-A-component.ts**、 **page—Bcomponent.ts** both do that:

```
// import
import { ActionComponent } from '../action/action.component';

// @Component has providers
providers: [ActionComponent]

// constructor
constructor( private actionComponent: ActionComponent ){ }

// init and add event
ngOnInit() {
    this.actionComponent.addEvent( this.tapIt() );
    this.actionComponent.onSubmit(); // this is test, it does work 
  }

// self event
tapIt() {
    return {
      handle: () => {
        console.log('Page A tap it'); // B is 'Page B tap it'
      }
    };
  }
```

finally in **main-component** include they, nothing special:

```
<page-a></page-a>
<page-b></page-b>
```

and module have them all, the above is all the test preparation, but in fact, the click event of action.component does not work, I’ll get error msg : Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined.

I know that the entity executed by **(click) = "onSubmit ()"** may not be a function implemented by page-A, page-B, but what should I do?
I don't want to create a service component for this requirement. Is there a way to accomplish this without using a service?

thank every help.

Comment: dude in onSubmit() method you are calling this.eventList[0].handle(); but addEvent(event) not get called before so this.eventList doesn't contain anything that's why you are getting this error

Comment: Yes, I found that this is indeed the case. When I click and log eventList, eventList are empty. but what should I do?

Comment: you should call the method addEvent(event) when you want to add event before submit.

Comment: ok, I try again, thank you.

Comment: I don't just understand why you are try to inject  actionComponent   in angular normally services is injected and you are injecting component that simply doesn't make any sense read about flow of angular mostly services, @input() , @output() directives

Comment: Yes, originally I also tend to use services, but my boss did n’t want me to use services on action.component and burned my time for this

Comment: then you can pass the event data through @input() to action component and save this event into your event list in ngOninit() and then do your further processing first you need to understand creation of instance of component is done by angular and  if you inject something into the components that need to be injectable (read @Injectable) so that angular can understand it need to be injected and angular creates it's instance for you.

Comment: Yes, I got it! Indeed, as you said, since want to use component directly, then using input is indeed a better way. I'm really a ROM brain. Thank you very much for your help.